# Could mods have some access to flags through the mobile web interface?

Tags: feature-request, flags, moderator-tools, mobile-web

**Background**

I was recently away from home for about two weeks.  On some of the sites I moderate I wasn't the only one, so we were already down a little on moderator attention.  While I wasn't going to pay as much attention to SE as usual, I was hoping to help out some.

Unfortunately, using my phone I couldn't even *see* flags, let alone *handle* them.  Now some flags would be hard to handle on a phone anyway, but some are easy (yeah, delete that; no, decline that; etc).  And even seeing the rest would make discussions in the mod chat room easier.

**Request**

On the mobile interface we can see the diamond notification for new meta posts, mod messages, and SE announcements.  That's good.  Could we *also* have the flags notification, the one that leads to the flags page?

I don't think we want to try to jam the in-page flags overlay into the mobile interface; there just isn't room for that.  But for *tempoary* use on a *phone*, the following workflow seems quite acceptable to me: (1) Go to flags list. (2) Read a flag and then click through to read the post. Make a decision. (3) Use the "back" button to go back to the flags page and handle the flag.

I wouldn't want to do that all the time or when using a keyboard and mouse, but for a touch interface with limited real-estate this seems ok.  This also means that if I want to discuss the flag with other mods, I can copy the URL of the flagged post and head off to chat.

Note that I am asking for this in the mobile *web* interface, not the Android or iOS apps.  That would be ok too, but I've not had much luck navigating efficiently in the Android app so I don't use it for my regular browsing, just for notifications.

Note also that I am aware of the "use desktop site" option in mobile browsers, *but* that's quite unworkable for me at that screen size.  I tried that once or twice while I was away but quickly gave up.

Comment: FWIW, I just use the desktop interface and zoom WAAAAAY in

Comment: Yeah, I am getting used to handling flags through the desktop interface, though I wouldn't mind a mobile interface.  Mobile chat on the other hand...

Comment: Seconded. Tools should enable moderators to stay on top of things, even on the go.

Comment: @Shog9 I tried that, but I had to do too much scrolling to be able to read things.  Someone with vision closer to 20/20 might fare better, but phones really weren't made for regular web pages. :-)

Comment: @Jamal [ChatSEy](http://stackapps.com/q/4659/21539) has made a *huge* difference to me.  I got it for "reply" alone.

Comment: I don't have Android. :-(

Comment: ChatSEy *did* make a huge difference for me, until changes to chat broke it. :-(

Comment: This discussion is now continued here three years later: [Facilitate flagging and use of moderator tools from mobile devices](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309644/facilitate-flagging-and-use-of-moderator-tools-from-mobile-devices)